# State updated in constructor appears only partially in render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this React Native code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight, View, Text,  Platform } from 'react-native';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default class MyList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {autoPlay: true, width: 0};

      this._onScroll = this._onScroll.bind(this);
      this._goToNextPage = this._goToNextPage.bind(this);
      this._startAutoPlay = this._startAutoPlay.bind(this);
      this._stopAutoPlay = this._stopAutoPlay.bind(this);

      this._myIndex = 0;
  }

  render() {
    console.log("In render, this.state: " + JSON.stringify(this.state));
    console.log("In render, this._myIndex: " + this._myIndex);
    //some other code
  }
}
```

This prints:

```
ReactNativeJS: In render, this.state: {"autoPlay":true}
ReactNativeJS: In render, this._myIndex: 0
```

Why is `this.state` only partially initialized in the `constructor`?

The state should be set to `{autoPlay: true, width: 0}` but it's only set to `{"autoPlay":true}`.

I know the `constructor` initialises other variables such as `this._myIndex` correctly because If I change the value I give them in the constructor, that will be shown in the logs.

However, `this.state` is not initialised correctly in the constructor. Why?

Comment: the code you posted looks fine (I've tested it)

Comment: I can confirm the above

Comment: I've added all the code from the `constructor`. I don't think any other piece of code is relevant. I'm checking the logs with `react-native log-android` and `adb logcat ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V`. I'm running MacOS(probably not relevant).

Comment: How about any lifecycle events?

Comment: Out of interest, what happens if you set the initial state for **width** to a truthy value? ...say 1

Comment: Try logging the state without the stringify.

Comment: In fiddle you can see both fields initialized... https://fiddle.jshell.net/rigobauer/nc5qk61u/ Is there any place in the rest of your code where you can be reloading the state and removing that `width` field?